# How to create boost multi_index key to a member of member?

Tags: c++, boost-multi-index

Let's say I have following:

```
struct foo {
   int i;
};

struct bar {
    foo f;
};
```

is there a way to create a key to `f.i` (except wrapping to function) for container, holding `struct bar`?

Straightforward way does not seem to work:

```
namespace mpi = boost::multi_index;
typedef mpi::multi_index_container<bar,
     mpi::indexed_by< mpi::hashed_unique<bar,
         mpi::member< bar, int, &bar::fo.i>>
> > Foobar;
```

Answer (score 3):

multi-index's `member` index helper is only designed to access direct members of the value class, and can't be composed in a nested way.

Instead use the intended mechanism and write your own key extractor. It will make code maintenance much easier than trying to utilize the basic built in functionality for something it was never supposed to accomplish.

```
struct foo_i_from_bar
{
    typedef int result_type;
    result_type operator()(const bar& b) const { return b.f.i; }
};

typedef boost::multi_index::multi_index_container<bar,
     boost::multi_index::indexed_by< boost::multi_index::hashed_unique<foo_i_from_bar>
         > > Foobar;
```

Comment: Then it would be easier to use lambda instead, but as far as I know lambda does not work with multi_index

Answer (score 1):

It's ugly but it works.

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>

struct foo {
    int i;
};

struct bar {
    typedef int result_type;
    foo f;
};

namespace mpi = boost::multi_index;

typedef mpi::member< bar, int, (int bar::*)( offsetof(bar,f.i) )> bar_member;
                                         //  ^^^^^^^^ bar::f.i      

typedef mpi::multi_index_container< bar, mpi::indexed_by< mpi::hashed_unique<bar, bar_member > > > Foobar;

Foobar foobar;
```

... this works too ...

```
typedef mpi::member< bar, int, (int bar::*)( (size_t)&(((bar*)0)->f.i) )> bar_member;
```

Comment: Why there is `result_type` typedef in struct `bar`? Is it required?

Comment: @Slava I got en error when I tried it out. Adding `result_type`was my fix.